# Python String Expression format

Tags: python, string, format

I am not understanding the meaning of each of the terms in the curly brackets (I was a bit overwhelmed with this source https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)

```
def format_money(amount):
    return '${:.2f}'.format(amount)
```

I know that it return this format: $39.99 but I don't know what each sign means. Could someone explain?

Comment: It reduces the decimal part to two places, see https://pyformat.info/

Comment: I get that, but I am wondering how. What does the colon mean, what does the . mean, the f??

Comment: Have you tried searching a bit online? A good resource will explain that much better than we can here within an answer...

Comment: I agree with that, one source I found was the link I found mentioned in my post, but they provide tons of cases but I could not find this particular one.

Comment: @Tartaglia I think this is off topic. I’m voting to close this as having answerers rephrase other easily available resources for you is a poor fit for Stack Overflow, and certainly not terribly valuable.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $ is outside of formatted string placeholder

{: is the beginning of the formatted string
.2f is the fixed number of places after the decimal
} end of your place holder

i find it always fun to experiment to test a function or a module, you can also format the date, output, lots of other stuff... all in that lovely reference page

Comment: Thanks, so do I always begin that line of code with this part then: {:  ?

Comment: you don't have to begin the line of code with that, but wherever you are formatting a string.  i find myself using them often in print statements
example from docs
```
points = 19
total = 22
print('Correct answers: {:.2%}'.format(points/total))
```
'Correct answers: 86.36%'

Comment: i would reply in chat or comments, but don\'t have enough street cred yet

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Yeah, I got ya. That was very helpful though, highly appreciate it!!